# And operator behaves odd

Tags: c#, and-operator

I have two variable spn and fmi.

(3064,11),(3064,14),(3064,16),(123,11)

spn gets the first values(3064,3064,3064,123) and fmi gets (11,14,16,11)

and here is the code :

```
    if ((Spn != 3064) && (Fmi != 11) || (Fmi != 16))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Spn:{0}  Fmi:{1}   Added", Spn, Fmi);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Spn:{0}  Fmi:{1}   skipped", Spn, Fmi);
    }
```

So I want the output to show :

```
(3064,14) added
(123,11) added
(3064,16) skipped
(3064,11) skipped
```

the above code is wrong and this one is the correct one :

```
 if ((Spn != 3064) || (Fmi != 11) && (Fmi != 16))
```

I really don't get it. it is exactly opposite of what I wrote before and expected to be correct! can anybody help ?

Comment: Can you post the whole text you expect, including "added" and "skipped"?

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to do? `(Spn != 3064) && (Fmi != 11) || (Fmi != 16)` on its own doesn't mean anything to us.

Comment: Have you tried adding parenthesis? Maybe the problem is just that the compiler is matching subexpressions differently on how you expect them to be matched. Say for example, that you really want: ((Spn != 3064) && (Fmi != 11)) || (Fmi != 16). The meaning is totally different!

Comment: I want to skip (3064,16), (3064,11) and add others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example output it sounds like you want to add an item to the list if:

- Spn is not 3064 OR IF
- Fmi is something other than 11 or 16

Translating those two parts into code, we get:

Spn is not 3064

```
Spn != 3064
```

Fmi is something other than 11 or 16

or expressed another way,

Fmi is not 11 and Fmi is not 16

```
 Fmi != 11 && Fmi != 16
```

Now putting those two together using the OR in my bulleted list above, you get:

```
Spn != 3064 || (Fmi != 11 && Fmi != 16)
```

And we can optionally remove the parentheses because `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`:

```
Spn != 3064 || Fmi != 11 && Fmi != 16
```

And this is exactly the expression that you yourself found to work.

It might be easier to put everything in terms of what you want to skip rather than what to add. In other words,

Skip a pair if:

- Spn is 3064 AND
- Fmi is 11 or 16

So

```
Spn == 3064 && (Fmi = 11 || Fmi == 16)
```

(the parentheses are necessary this time)

```
if (Spn == 3064 && (Fmi = 11 || Fmi == 16))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Spn:{0}  Fmi:{1}   skipped", Spn, Fmi);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Spn:{0}  Fmi:{1}   Added", Spn, Fmi);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in C#.

`&&` has higher precedence than `||` and is evaluated first.

In your correct version, it evaluates `(Fmi != 11) && (Fmi != 16)` first and then the result of that OR `(Spn != 3064)`. Only (3064,14) and (123,11) match.

In your incorrect version `(Spn != 3064) && (Fmi != 11)` is evaluated first and the result of that is applied to OR `(Fmi != 16)`. This is a match for (3064,14), (3064,16) and (123,11).

---

The rules that you want the selection to happen are not really clear to me so please decide yourself, applying the answer given.

If you want to enforce some order of precedence, you can put some groups into parentheses `( )`, e.g.

```
(A || B) && C
```

OR will be evaluated before AND.

Comment: Even with operator precedence reversed, the original code wouldn't give the desired result.

Comment: @DanPuzey I'm not going to give the solution here as there's only 4 items and the rules to select some are not really clear. I'll leave it to OP to decide what's correct...

Comment: @Syzmon: Of course; I was just noting the fact that the OP's code makes little sense either way :)

Comment: @Szymon Your answer says "This happens because of operator precedence", but OP's problem is not the result of operator precedence. It just looks like it is. So your answer is not valid.

Comment: @JLRishe To be honest, I'm not really sure how OP wanted his code to work - for me it's too hard to establish a pattern based on 4 items and code that wouldn't work either way. It still looks to me that OP had problems with operators' precedence. Anyway, I gave +1 to your answer as it's more comprehensive and deserves the tick it got.

Comment: @Szymon I agree that a refresher on operator precedence would probably do OP some good. Thank you for the +1. That's very gracious of you.